# Тип таблиц для даты и времени

Tags: postgresql, mysql

Доброго времени суток :)

Раньше я использовал php'шную функцию time() для получения времени/даты и хранил всё в int, но в последнее время задумался о том, что это далеко не лучший вариант.
Подскажите какой тип таблиц лучше выбрать для хранения даты и времени?

З.Ы. предполагается, что в будущем вместо php с бд будет работать node.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если время не нужно сравнивать и никакие выборки с участием времени не нужны, то int вполне подойдет.

В остальных случаях - обратите внимание на DATETIME для даты и времени. И DATE просто для даты. И посмотрите заодно на функции MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME() и UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - пригодятся.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение)

Comment: и, кстати, во многих языках есть встроенные функции для работы со временем, которые очень сильно всё упрощают

В ПХП например:

http://ru2.php.net/strtotime

http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Как раз ищу функции для работы с DATATIME. Не подскажите таковые? А именно, мне нужны функции для получения даты в формате DATATIME, и вывода в нужном мне виде/формате (для этого можно использовать data(), как я предполагаю).

Первая ссылка, как я понял мне не подходит, а во-второй как-то я не совсем понял для чего тот класс нужен..

Comment: Вот так, например:

    echo date('d.m.Y', strtotime('2012-12-30 01:00:00'));

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо)